# Swift partially decode JSON and keep unparsed data

Tags: json, swift

I'd like to decode a layered JSON protocol in parts. For example:

```json
{
    "eventType": "foo",
    ... other things
    "eventData": <some json of unknown structure>
}
```

and have this decode into a Swift type like..

```swift
struct EventWrapper: Decodable {
    eventType: String
    ... other things
    eventData: String
}
```

where the `eventData` string contains exactly `<some json of unknown structure>`, i.e. the entire value of that property left in the original JSON encoded format. The intent would be to use information in this outer layer to decide where to send the inner layer. Once decided, only the inner layer data would be transferred and the recipient would understand its format and decode it further.

Some things I've tried that aren't quite what I want:

1. I can omit `eventData` entirely to parse just `eventType` and `... other things`. But this option doesn't seem to allow easy access to the remaining unparsed data.
2. I can do a partial decode (as in #1) and then dispatch the original raw message to the next layer. This requires transferring unnecessary outer wrapper data and requires the next layer to understand and re-parse the outer layer.
3. With a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method I can conditionally decode `eventData` to different types based on the value of `eventType`. But I can't seem to choose to *not decode* a particular property or access the un-decoded bytes.

Comment: The code in question is an intermediary that doesn't understand how to decode `eventData`. I'm not asking to start decoding at an arbitrary level. Rather, while decoding (from the top) to save the bytes of skipped properties. The fact that they are skippable indicates that the Swift parsers know their boundaries. The fact that you can conditionally decode on a property by property basis suggests that those bytes exist, waiting for you to tell them how to decode. I could straightforwardly write a JSON parser from scratch that does what I need, but would rather not if there is another way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that I can skip them entirely with `CodingKey`, but I want something in between. Don't skip, but also don't fully decode into Swift objects. Just store the undecoded property as a string on the Swift object.

Comment: Just to clarify. You want the content of `eventData` property to be decoded to a `String` instead of whatever this would represent as custom object?

Comment: @burnsi yes. some more specific and concrete examples: The eventData property of `{"eventType":"foo","eventData":[1,2,3]}` would get decoded as a string with value "[1,2,3]". Likewise, the same code would decode `{"eventType":"bar","eventData":[[1],[2]]}` with the eventData string being "[[1],[2]]". The code doesn't know the schema inside of `eventData` so it just wants to pull the bytes out so they can be sent to another program that does know.